# Dynamic SQL: how can I retrieve data from 3 different tables and count the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to count the number of times people have selected a certain option in a choice field (represented as a -element with options on a webpage).

The name of choice fields are stored in the `CodeType` table.

```
> select [CodeTypeID] from [CodeType] where [Name] = 'Favorite Fruit'

CodetypeID
----------
1000210
```

I can find the choices by querying the `CodytypeID`-table by the found `CodetypeID`:

```
> select [ArtifactID], [Name] from [Code] where [CodetypeID] = '1000210'

ArtifactID   Name
-------------------
1039477     Apple
1039478     Pear
1039479     Banana
1039912     Peach
```

Each choice field has a separate table (named `CodeArtifact_XXXX` where XXXX is the `CodetypeID` found above). By counting the number of rows for each option (identified by `CodeArtifactID`) I can see how many times a choice was selected:

```
> select
>   count(case when [CodeArtifactID] = '1039477' then 1 else null end) as 'Apple'
>   count(case when [CodeArtifactID] = '1039478' then 1 else null end) as 'Pear'
>   count(case when [CodeArtifactID] = '1039479' then 1 else null end) as 'Banana'
>   count(case when [CodeArtifactID] = '1039477' then 1 else null end) as 'Peach'
> from
>   [CodeArtifact_1000210]

Apple   Pear    Banana    Peach
-------------------------------
12      0       7         4
```

However, I have to count the choices for many more choicefields. Therefore, hardcoding all of this is not an option.

I think the only solution here is to use dynamic SQL -- something I have no experience with. Could someone give me an example of how I could count for any choicefield, the number of times their options are chosen?

I other words: by only changing the choicefield `[Name]` in the beginning (`Favorite Fruit`, 'Marital Status', 'Latest Diploma', etc), the choices should be looked up and counted automatically.

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: EDIT: I think Tab is leading you in a good direction.

Comment: Wow, that database design... A table like `CodeArtifact_1000210` should not exist.

Comment: i agree with Tom H - fix the design and the queries will be easier.

Comment: I cannot fix the design. It is a propietary product and I am not allowed, nor have the user-rights to fix the design. I can only query against this database. Therefore I am asking for help :)

Comment: @TomH what if those tables are code generated table name or it is multitenant database with table per account model? nothing wrong here until you know more details

Answer (score 0):

You can directly execute the following code..

```
    Declare
        @CodeName   nVarChar(100),
        @CodeType   nVarChar(100),
        @ColumnName nVarChar(MAX),
        @DynamicSQL nVarChar(MAX);


    Set @CodeName = 'Favorite Fruit';

    Select
       @CodeType = Convert(varChar, [CodetypeID])
    From
       [dbo].[CodeType]
    Where
       [Name] = @CodeName;

    Create Table #tmpCode
        (
            [ArtifactID]    int,
            [Name]          VarChar(100)
        )

Set @DynamicSQL =
    'Insert Into #tmpCode
        Select
            [ArtifactID],
            [Name]
        From
            [dbo].[CodeType]                As ct
                Inner Join  [dbo].[Code]    As cd
                    On ct.[CodetypeID] = cd.[CodetypeID]' +
                'Inner Join [dbo].[CodeArtifact_' + @CodeType + ']  As ca
                    On ca.[CodeArtifactID] = cd.[ArtifactID]
        Where
            ct.[Name] = @CodeName';

Exec(@DynamicSQL);


    Select @ColumnName =
        STUFF((
            Select
                ',' + QUOTENAME([Name])
            From
                #tmpCode
            Group By
                [Name]
        For XML Path(''), Type).value('.', 'nVarChar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


    Set @DynamicSQL =
        'Select ' + @ColumnName + ' From
            (Select [ArtifactID], [Name] From #tmpCode) tmp
            Pivot (Count([ArtifactID]) For [Name] In (' + @ColumnName + ')) As pvt ';

    Exec sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
    -- Exec (@DynamicSQL);


    Drop Table
        #tmpCode
```